# Rust's `Sender/Receiver` is forced to be `Sync + Send`

Tags: rust

```
pub struct AsyncTransporter {
    stream: Arc<dyn AsyncRW + Send + Sync>,
}
```

Suppose that a library expects `AsyncTransporter` to be `Send + Sync`, and that `dyn AsyncRW` is a struct that holds a channel tuple:

```
pub struct SmolSocket {
    channel: (Sender<Arc<Packet>>, Receiver<Arc<Packet>>),
}
```

How can I make it such that `SmolSocket` implements `Send + Sync` safely? Even though `SmolSocket` holds `Sender` and `Receiver`, it's going to be inside an `Arc` so I don't see how it could go wrong.

Unfortunately `AsyncTransporter` must be `Send+Sync`.

Context: `AsyncTransporter` is the `connector` in https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.9/hyper/client/struct.Builder.html#method.build so it automatically needs to be `Send+Sync`. At least this is what I think.

Comment: What are... all of these things?

Comment: If `Packet` is not Send+Sync and you want to send `Arc<Packet>` around to share a `Packet` among threads, maybe you want `Arc<Mutex<Packet>>` instead?

Comment: @user4815162342 but it looks like `Sender` is never `Sync` even when its inside type is

Comment: The `Sender` from the standard-library channels is not `Sync` because it's designed to be cloned and moved to the thread it operates from. If you need a `Sync` sender, you can use `crossbeam` or `flume` channels, depending on whether you need a blocking or an async interface.